# group name can't start with number?

Tags: python, regex

It looks like I can't use regex like this one,

```
(?P<74xxx>[0-9]+)
```

With re package it would raise and error,

```
sre_constants.error: bad character in group name u'74xxx'
```

It looks like I can't use group names that starts with a number, why?

P.S golang does not have such problem, so does many other languages

Comment: If you look at the preceding line which raises the exception: `if not name.isidentifier()` - I'm guessing it's because named groups are interned or otherwise optimised as part of `re.compile`'s cache (and it's easier to do so if they're valid identifiers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> Group names must be valid Python identifiers

As the variables, identifiers mustn't start with a number in Python. See more about identifiers [here](https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/identifiers.html):

```
identifier  ::=     (letter|"_") (letter | digit | "_")*
letter      ::=     lowercase | uppercase
lowercase   ::=     "a"..."z"
uppercase   ::=     "A"..."Z"
digit       ::=     "0"..."9"
```

Answer (score -2):

If this is the pattern you are searching `r'(?P<74xxx>[0-9]+)'` and you wanted to include `?` in your search pattern then you have to prepend `\` with it since it is the special character in python. So your search pattern should be `r'(\?P<74xxx>[0-9]+)'`.

Comment: why down votes, I have given the right answer. group name should not just start with a ? since it is a special character

Comment: Probably because this is not what OP is asking?